# How many prime ideals are fixed by a given permutation?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose $L$ is a finite Galois field extension of the rational number field $\mathbb{Q}$, and $B$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $L$. Let $\sigma$ be an element of the Galois group Gal($L/\mathbb{Q}$). My question is

> Are there infinitely many prime ideals of $B$ which are fixed by $\sigma$,
>   i.e., is the set $\{\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{Spec} B\mid \sigma(\mathfrak{p})=\mathfrak{p}\}$ nonempty and infinite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let $G$ be the subgroup of the Galois group generated by $\sigma$, and let $K$ be the fixed field of $G$. Then $L/K$ is cyclic, and by Chebotarev there are infinitely many prime ideals in $K$ that are inert in $L$.